# Visual Studio Installer won't launch

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

When attempting to install Visual Studio 2015 using the download provided on visualstudio.com, the installer immediately shows an error:

[image: Error]

As far as I know, there are no error logs at the time of crash. Any further information you need, I'd be happy to provide.

I am running the latest Windows 10. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Similar kind of error happened in installing Autodesk. Seems the problem is the antivirus software in that case. Please disable the software and try to install it again. Refer this [link](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-The-system-cannot-open-the-device-or-file-specified.html). Dont know whether it will work in your case but still give it a try.

Comment: I actually don't have any antivirus running.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7dd0952-9128-46f5-a40c-2433afa18f08/system-cannot-find-the-file-specifieddebugging-error?forum=vcgeneral) link.  Take a not at the last comment too. @mattrick

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio installed yet, when trying to launch the installer I immediately get that error message.

Comment: do you still have the partially installed files in your directive ?

Comment: I did, but after removing them I still had the same issue.

Comment: Did you enable the developer mode in windows 10 settings ?